# Find escaped characters in a string line

Tags: c++, string, function, find

Using the std library, and the function `find`, how can I know if there are any escaped characters in the given string ?

For instance :

```
string line = "bla bla bla \n blabla";
bool hasEscapedSequence = (line.find("\n",0) < line.size());
```

This obviously won't work since the `\n` in the `find` will be escaped. If I try `(line.find("\\n",0) < line.size());`, it doesn't seem to change anything

How should I do ?

Comment: This would be easily done in c using pointers.

Comment: @iharob How ? (Basically I do only have this "string line")

Comment: At least in this example, your string does not have any escaped characters, but an actual newline.

Comment: `\n` is exactly what you should be searching for here, not `\\n`.

Comment: I'm rather sure that the '\n' character gets compiled away into a single Newline character (0x0A), so searching for "\n" should work, unless you used "bla bla bla \\n blabla" as your source string, at which point "\\n" would work?

Comment: Your code works fine, see http://ideone.com/3XXQWn

Comment: Oh, i didn't notice the escaped character was `n`??? `'\n'` is a single character.

Comment: @iharob doesn't make a difference here, `"\n"` overload searches for a string with a single character

Comment: The compiler will translate the `'\n'` to a newline in *both* strings, which leads me to ask, have you *tried* it?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious : Ok I get it. But how would you do if you have to find the presence of a backslash ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
line.find("\n",0)
```

Will return the position of the cursor where it will find the substring. If the substring is not found it will return string::npos.
And so it should not be compared with the size.

```
bool hasEscapedSequence = (line.find("\n") != string::npos);
```

Comment: `line.find("\n",0) > -1` ? `line.find("\n",0) != -1`?

Comment: This is not C so `-1` is not a good idea. `npos` should be used here.

Comment: Edited for npos just before you posted. Thanks Captain Obvlious :P

Comment: Almost a good answer, `0` is however redundant as it is the default parameter to `std::string::find`. And **no**, `string::npos` is not less than `line.size()`, usually it is defined as a `std::size_t` initialized to `-1`, so it is the maximum value a `std::size_t` can hold (since the latter is an unsigned type). Can convince yourself by trying `std::cout << std::string::npos << std::endl;`