# How can I know if the Backslash is in my string?

Tags: c++, find

This question directly follows up this one (where I got to understand how the function `find` works) : [Find escaped characters in a string line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028231/find-escaped-characters-in-a-string-line)

Now, considering I have :

```
string line = "bla bla bla \i blabla"
bool hasBackslash = (line.find("\",0) != string::npos);
```

I just want to know if my line contains `\`, but, of course, in the `find`, what I wrote will just escape the quote character.

This line `bool hasBackslash = (line.find("\\",0) != string::npos);` will look for `\\` in the code.

How am I able to know if the given line contains a backslash ?

Comment: You need to scape the backslash for it to be explicitly in your string, so your test string is failing and I really doubt your code will compile with this `line.find("\",0)`...

Comment: To have literal \\ your string should be: `string line = "bla bla bla \\i blabla"`

Comment: this has nothing special to do with regular expressions, functions or C.

Comment: any common compiler should warn you that `\i` is an unrecognized character escape sequence. and your debugger should show you the content of your  `line` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This line `bool hasBackslash = (line.find("\\",0) != string::npos);` will look for `\\` in the code."

no it won't. that's exactly what you need if you want to search for a single backslash.

Comment: (Not my downvote, I'm just trying to get an answer)

http://ideone.com/u82ngq 

Returns false to my boolean while my line contains a \. 
In an other comment, there is written that a compiler will notice the \i. Let's suppose it doesn't.

Comment: @Marc-O Except that your line **doesn't** contain a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

To embed backshlashes in a string literal you need to escape them

```
string line = "bla bla bla \i blabla"
bool hasBackslash = (line.find("\",0) != string::npos);
```

should be

```
string line = "bla bla bla \\i blabla"
bool hasBackslash = (line.find("\\",0) != string::npos);
```

Answer (score 0):

The representation in C of backslash is `"\\"`. Note: backslash is an escape character.

For example, when you read a backslash for standard input or from a file it will be can be represented in a string with `"\\"`

I've prepared an example where you can test it out:
https://ideone.com/aTCeSL

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    cout << "Enter a backslash" << endl;
    getline(cin, line);
    bool hasBackslash = (line.find('\\') != string::npos);
    cout << (hasBackslash ? "You have entered a backslash" : "No backslash found");
    return 0;
}
```